# Ошибка "некорректный запрос" при получении списка языков в яндекс:api

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь получить список языков для перевода, но почему то я не могу этого сделать выдается ошибка про некорректный запрос.Вот код для этого.
Суть в том, что  смотрю инструкцию к апи не могу найти что не так.
[Тут инструкция](https://tech.yandex.ru/translate/doc/dg/reference/getLangs-docpage/)

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    namespace parsenum
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?"
                                                       + "key=mysecrettoker"
                                                       + "&ui=ru"
                                                       + "&lang=t");


request.Method = "POST";
   var response = request.GetResponse();

                using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException()))
                {
                    string line;

                    if ((line = stream.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Translation translation = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Translation>(line);

                    }
                }

                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        class Translation
        {
            public string code { get; set; }
            public string lang { get; set; }

        }


    }
```

Comment: В документации сказано - отправлять методом POST. А ещё у вас в коде запрос на translate, а вы пишете - "хочу получить список языков". Это всё о внимательности больше, а не о коде.

Comment: @AK да там так сказано, но я думал. что  вебреквест делает это уже.Подправил но ошибка все равно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, в документации сказано - отправлять методом POST.

А ещё у вас в коде запрос идёт на адрес /translate, а вы пишете - "хочу получить список языков" (в документации - /getLangs).

В общем, как-то так в итоге:

```
var key = "trnsl.1.1.2фывафывафывафыва";
var request = WebRequest.Create($"https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/getLangs?ui=en&key={key}");
request.Method = "POST";

var postData = "";
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();

var response = request.GetResponse ();
using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException()))
{
    string line;

    if ((line = stream.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        //line.Dump();
        Translation translation = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Translation>(line);
        //translation.Dump();
    }
}
```

Ответ:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И ещё - у вас класс десериализации неправильный, вот так надо:

```
public partial class Translation
{
    [JsonProperty("dirs")]
    public string[] Dirs { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("langs")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Langs { get; set; }
}
```

Его я получил при помощи сервиса https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp - рекомендую на будущее, чтобы не путаться.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ а вот что есть такое .Dump()? у меня оно  подсвечивается как ошибка

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch Это типа Console.WriteLine - для дебага. У вас нет, потому что вы код пишете в студии, а я такие скетчи пишу в linqpad - это у него такой удобный метод.

Comment: ок понял ,спасибо